# Tagging udeploy versions

Tags: git, jenkins, udeploy

- For my project we use **git**, **Jenkins**, and **udeploy**
- On git occasionally we “**tag**” a commit, i.e. **“release 1.0”**
- For each project, we have at least two Jenkins job, one that builds the “**develop**” branch and one for “**master**”
- On udeploy we sometimes deploy from develop and sometimes from master. The develop and master have different job numbers on Jenkins, one could be #14 and other #65.  In **udeploy > versions** this jobs are identified as `“ProjectName-ShortVersionOfGitCommit-JenkinsJobNumber”` i.e. `MyApp-bcc27g9-9`. This is hard to read and identify, especially that we have several branches and Jenkins jobs.

How would I make the version more readable by changing it to `“ProjectName-Branch-Tag-JenkinsJobNumber”` where tag is optional, i.e. `MyApp-develop-release1.1-9` or just `MyApp-develop-9`.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Build Name Setter Plugin' and the 'Token Macro Plugin' allow to customize the name given to a build job based on virtually anything you can wish for. E.g:

```
${GIT_BRANCH}-${GIT_REVISION,length=8}-${ENV,var="BUILD_TYPE"}
```

(assuming you set an environment variable called BUILD_TYPE). Probably there's even a built-in variable which gives you the tag(s) which you can make use of.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin